# Expose template-template parameter of type

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

I have a type that depends on a **template template parameter**:

```cpp
template<typename X_, template<typename, typename> class Y_>
struct A { /*...*/ };
```

which I construct with a factory function:

```cpp
template<typename X_, template<typename, typename> class Y_>
A<X_, Y_> make() {
    return A<X_, Y_> { /*...*/ };
};
```

Now, I would like to add a factory function that takes an `A` by reference and assigns to it without me having to restate its template parameters:

```cpp
template<typename A_>
void make(A_& a) {
    a = make<typename A_::X, typename A_::Y>();
}
```

I added two template aliases to `A` to achieve this:

```cpp
template<typename X_, template<typename, typename> class Y_>
struct A { 
    using X = X_;
    template <typename... T>
    using Y = Y_<T...>;
    /* ... */ 
};
```

and then I try compiling:

```cpp
A<int, std::vector> v;
make(v);
```

which yields, [see Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/73EqiL):

```
<source>: In instantiation of 'void make(A_&) [with A_ = A<int, std::vector>]':
<source>:24:11:   required from here
<source>:18:9: error: 'typename A<int, std::vector>::Y' names 'template<class ... T> using Y = class std::vector<T ...>', which is not a type

   18 |     a = make<typename A_::X, typename A_::Y>();

      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I do not understand why GCC 9.2 does not agree with me that `Y` is a type.
How should I communicate my intensions to the compiler correctly?

Answer (score 5):

It is not `typename` but `template` you should use:

```
template<typename A_>
void make(A_& a) {
    a = make<typename A_::X, A_::template Y>();
}
```

In addition

```
template<typename X_, template<typename, typename> class Y_>
struct A { 
    using X = X_;
    template <typename... T>
    using Y = Y_<T...>;
    /* ... */ 
};
```

`Y` and `Y_` are not equivalent, you need

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
using Y = Y_<T1, T2>;
```

And I think it is only since C++17 they would be equivalent then.

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f63184e4ad1b960c)

Comment: How are `T1` and `T2` evaluated? Are they deduced from `Y_` within the `using` declaration?

Comment: @DanielLangr: you have to provide them (as for `Y`): `Y_<char, int>` or `A::Y<char, int>`.